# How to select all checkbox and get value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

In foreach loop there is checkbox for each row.

Code As Bellow.

```
foreach($rpd_records as $rpd_newslater_records)
{
    $rp_ne_value = maybe_unserialize($rpd_newslater_records->meta_value); ?>
    <tr>
        <input type="hidden" class="rpd_meta_id" name="rpd_meta_id" value="<?php echo $rp_ne_records->meta_id; ?>">
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><?php echo $rp_ne_value['product_id']; ?></td>
        <td> <div class="send_mail_btn" style="display: inline;">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="rpd_send_it">Send</a></div></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
} ?>

<button type="button" id="sendAll" class="main"><span class="sub"></span> Send All </button>
```

**What I should :** when i click on SendAll Button then its all checkbox are selected and get each of Row Hidden Value using Jquery.

Can you suggest me.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to just alert the values from all checkboxes ?

Comment: you can use click event of SendAllButton to check all checkbox then use `.each()` to iterate through all `tr` then use `.find()` with classname to get the input then use `.val()` to get the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you;

```
$("#sendAll").click(function(e) {
    $(":checkbox").attr("checked", true);    

    var values = $('input.rpd_meta_id[type="hidden"]').map(function(){
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    alert(values);
});
```

Comment: In additional if i want to get One by one hidden values then how can i do.

Comment: Try using this : `$('input.rpd_meta_id[type="hidden"]').each(function(index, element){
        alert($(this).val());
    })` . This will alert the hidden field values one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can

1) traverse to closest `tr` element

2) find hidden input in it.

3) use `.map()` and get jquery object of all hidden input values

4) convert to array using `.get()`

```
 $('#sendAll').click(function(){
  var inputcheckboxes = $('input:checked').attr("checked", true);    
  var hiddenValForChecked = inputcheckboxes.find('.rpd_meta_id').map(function(){
    return this.value;
  }).get();
  console.log(hiddenValForChecked);
 });
```

Here `hiddenValForChecked` represents array of values of hidden fields.